# JavaScript inside Ajax - Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8

I would like to add a Javascript at the end of some ajax content,
It works fine on firefox but internet explorer print the script without running it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.tablesorter.addParser({
        id: 'title',
        is: function(s)
        {
             return false;
        },
        format: function(s)
        {
             s= s.substring(s.indexOf('<span class="title">')+24,s.length-30);
             return s.replace(' ','');
        },
        type: 'text'
    });

    $.tablesorter.addParser({
        id: 'price',
        is: function(s)
        {
             return false;
        },
        format: function(s)
        {
             s= s.substring(0,s.length-3);
             return s.replace(' ','');
        },
        type: 'digit'
    });
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
       $("#result").tablesorter({
            headers: {
                0: {sorter:'title'},
                1: {sorter:'price'},
                2: {sorter: false}
            }
       });
    });
    </script>



function submitForm()
{
$("form#search").ajaxSubmit({
            beforeSubmit: function(formData, jqForm, options) {
                $("#window").html('<div style="text-align:center; display:block;"><img src="../images/commun/spinner.gif" /></div>');
                return true;
            },
            success: function(msg, statut) {
                $("#window").html(msg);
                return false;
            }
            });
}
```

Comment: is this the script that you want to add? How do you add it? what do you mean by "at the end of some ajax content"?

Comment: Do you have an example of invoking the ajax method? The code above doesn't seem to have any relevance to the question

Comment: @Marius the bit of code containing the javascript bit is loaded with ajax with the submitForm function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [getScript](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getScript) to load and run scripts. You can't mix script with html content. Also make sure that the context-type of the server's response is set to javascript MIME type, like 'text/javascript'.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem, what I did was just put the script content inside of a div with a special classname.  Once I get the response back and enter it into the DOM, I pull out that script content and simply eval() it.  This works in all browsers :-)

Answer (score 0):

The cause of error 80020101 is that IE can't load/trigger scripts returned with AJAX in JQuery 1.6 if the script is wrapped in a cdata comment.
So, remove the CDATA (<-- ... -->) in the code, and it should work.